# Form submit issue when invoking click?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a small program that loads a webpage into the form submits the form on the 
page automaticlly  - this is apart of a larger project but i cant get this part work properly.

This [**web page**](http://www.court.gov.il/NGCS.Web.Site/HomePage.aspx) offer Court cases results when the correct case number and date (mm-yy) is typed in and submitted.

I created a simple webBrowser in a form and called it `webBrowser1`.

And here is my Form.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);
            firstStep();
           // secondStep();
        }

        private void firstStep()
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.court.gov.il/NGCS.Web.Site/HomePage.aspx", System.UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        private void HandleRequest(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);
                HtmlElement caseNumber = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.All["Header1_CaseLocatorHeaderUC2_BamaCaseNumberTextBoxHT"];
                HtmlElement caseDate = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.All["Header1_CaseLocatorHeaderUC2_BamaMonthYearTextBoxHT"];

                caseNumber.Focus();
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(1)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(2)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(2)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(3)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(8)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(0)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(3)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(1)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(0)");

                HtmlElement inputTag = webBrowser1.Document.All["Header1_CaseLocatorHeaderUC2_SearchHeaderCaseButton"];
                inputTag.InvokeMember("Click");

        }
    }
}
```

[image: example]

As you can see - I'm typing the values as shown in the picture and then invoking a click on the button that submits this form, but it doesn't work!? this webpage is very tricky and uses scripts that validate the input and then sets the correct values to be submits and by the way he works only on IE < 10....

any idea please?

**EDIT:**
Its working now - I am firing the `invoke` twice but I don't have an idea what was the problem.

Now the new problem is that I added a button click that fires the process `btnGet_Click` and when triggering this function I get an error - it seems that `DetailsTag` is set to null... but when I un-comment the function in the `public Form1()` its working fine and loading the website as it should.

**What is the difference between calling the the function `firstStep()` in the button click / public form?**

**why I receive this error?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly object lock_ = new object();
        HtmlElement caseNumber;
        HtmlElement caseDate;
        HtmlElement DetailsTag; 
        int checks = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);
            //firstStep();
        }

        private void firstStep()
        {


                webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.court.gov.il/NGCS.Web.Site/HomePage.aspx", System.UriKind.Absolute);

        }       
        private void HandleRequest(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (checks < 1)
                {
                    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);
                    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(GetDetails);
                }
                caseNumber = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.All["Header1_CaseLocatorHeaderUC2_BamaCaseNumberTextBoxHT"];
                caseDate = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.All["Header1_CaseLocatorHeaderUC2_BamaMonthYearTextBoxHT"];

                if (caseNumber != null && caseDate != null)
                {

                caseNumber.Focus();
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(5)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(6)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(5)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(8)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(0)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(8)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(1)");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(3)");

                checks = 0;

                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No such case - enter a new one");
                }
        }
        private void GetDetails(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(GetDetails);
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(GetResults);

                DetailsTag = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl0_caseDetailsGrid_row1_ct6_Imagebutton1"];
                if (DetailsTag != null)
                {
                    DetailsTag.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error - try another case!");
                }
        }
        private void GetResults(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(GetResults);
                HtmlElement DetailsStatus = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl7_caseStatusIDlbl"];
                HtmlElement DetailsCourt = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl7_courtIDlbl"];
                HtmlElement DetailsType = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl7_caseTypeIDlbl"];
                HtmlElement DetailsAmount = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl7_claimAmountlbl"];
                HtmlElement DetailsPrev = webBrowser1.Document.All["_ctl7_privilegeIDlbl"];

                txtAmount.Text = DetailsAmount.InnerText;
                txtCount.Text = DetailsCourt.InnerText;
                txtPrev.Text = DetailsPrev.InnerText;
                txtStatus.Text = DetailsStatus.InnerText;
                txtType.Text = DetailsType.InnerText;
        }

        public void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);
                firstStep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are relying on a pretty hacky approach to populate the textboxes. Are you saying that the values you show in your picture have been populated by relying on this approach? It does not work on my computer. See... I cannot speak hewbrew and it is pretty difficult to analyse the code of this page/understand the popup messages. With a different code (the one I usually utilise), I am able to populate the textboxes and a warning message pops up after clicking on the button (with your code). If you don't get even that, I would post it as answer, otherwise not (don't like posting untested codes).

Comment: yes this is before i added the `invokemember`.... I know its not the common solution but nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said via comment, your approach for populating the textboxes is not too orthodox and, actually, is not working on my computer. The usual proceeding is relying on the `SetAttribute` function. Your code would become:

```
caseNumber.SetAttribute("value", "12283");
caseDate.SetAttribute("value", "03-10");
```

If I do that and then I use your `inputTag.InvokeMember("Click")`, the form is submitted (at least, no popup appears and the browser is redirected to a new page).

Comment: done that at the beginning and the browser redirect to the same page with no results... it seems that i need to trigger a script that validates the input on the date input tag, and when just setting the value that wont work.

Comment: Check my Edit please, I was able to receive the needed results but now I have another problem... maybe you can help me

Comment: @ShlomiHassid I am not sure about the new error you are reporting but it has nothing to do with calling the function from the button or the form load, but with calling the function twice/once. You are making the browser navigate to the same page twice and this might provoke a synchronisation problem while checking the DocumentCompleted Event; honestly, no idea. Better do things as they should be done: once each action and one after the other and there will not be any problem.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid Just to make sure that I did my point clear: with my code, the form is submitted (a new page with links on it appears), I wasn't just sure that this is the right information you want (mainly after saying that there is some weird function in the form, but everything seems pretty normal to me). Your hacky approach is not working on my computer; even if it would work, what I proposed is the expected way to deal with the problem and thus will work for sure (what you refer of redirecting to the same page does not make any sense; when you tested it you did something else wrong).

Comment: @ShlomiHassid Last clarification: what I am doing is getting a textbox object (for example, textBox1 you have added to your form) and changing the value on it by relying on its in-built property (textBox1.Text = "new text"). What you are doing is getting the given textBox object (textBox1 again) but inputting the value by emulating what a person would do (= simulating the keystrokes and focusing the typed text such that it is written in the textbox). Thus in the best scenario your approach would deliver the right values (what my approach will always do).